# Android Google GeofencingClient Not Sending Subsequent Events

Tags: android, location, geofencing

I'm trying to use the Google GeofencingClient (replacement of GeofencingApi) on Android. After setting up and adding the geofence, I do get a callback from the success listener and also receive the initial geofence entered/exited event in my IntentService. However, I do not receive any subsequent geofence events as I move in and out of the area. I have my radius set to 200 meters. Here's the code I'm using to add the geofence:

```
Geofence.Builder geoBuilder = new Geofence.Builder();
    geoBuilder.setRequestId(Constants.GEOFENCE_ID);
    geoBuilder.setNotificationResponsiveness(5 * 60 * 1000);
    geoBuilder.setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT);
    geoBuilder.setCircularRegion(latitude, longitude, 200f);
    geoBuilder.setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE);

    GeofencingRequest.Builder reqBuilder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    reqBuilder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER | GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT);
    reqBuilder.addGeofence(geoBuilder.build());

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, GService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    GeofencingClient client = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(context);
    Task task = client.addGeofences(reqBuilder.build(), pi);
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object o) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "FAIL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

In my IntentService, I log an entry when geofencingEvent.hasError() returns true. I have however not seen any error log entries, so no geofencing event has been posted to the service at all after the initial event.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am having the opposite issue, after switching from `LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences` to `geofencingClient.addGeofences` I no longer get the initial "enter" intent fired when I put the geofence just around my current location.

Before (did print "success" and fire the intent):

```
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                googleApiClient,
                request,
                createGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(status -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "onResult: " + status);
            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                mapsActivity.message("Adding geo-fence... Success");
                drawGeofence(position, radius);
            } else {
                mapsActivity.message("Adding geo-fence... FAILED!");
            }
        });
```

After (does print "success" but does not fire initial "Enter"):

```
        geofencingClient.addGeofences(request, createGeofencePendingIntent())
                .addOnSuccessListener((Void)->{
                    mapsActivity.message("Adding geo-fence... Success");
                    drawGeofence(position, radius);
                }).addOnFailureListener((Void)->{
                    // TODO: inform about fail
                    mapsActivity.message("Adding geo-fence... FAILED!");
                })
        ;
```

**Update:** After writing this, it just started working (no code change). The only difference is that in the meanwhile the app "Google" updated to version 7.18.50.21.arm64

Comment: Have you ever noticed that it failed to add the Geofence ? I've seen it not add the geofence, but I don't understand why it would fail for like the 2nd Geofence. Google gives no explanation, as far as I can tell.